# R: Sample unique X, Y pairs without duplication of Xs and Ys

Tags: r, unique, sample

I am having a hard time figuring how to program this in R: Given a number of X and Y pairs, such as

```
 X   Y
 9   1
 1   2
12   3
 8   4
 9   4
 4   5
16   6
18   7
 5   8
11   9
 4  10
 6  11
 6  12
14  13
18  13
20  13
13  14
20  15
20  16
```

I need to sample randomly n pairs that fulfil the condition that Xs and Ys are unique. For instance, if n=3 and using the data above, the following combinations (9,1) (4,5) (4,10) or (1,2) (14,13) (20,13) will be invalid because X=4 or Y=13 are duplicated in each of the solutions. However, (9,1) (1,2) and (8,4) will be a valid solution because the Xs and Ys are unique. Any help will be moooooost welcome.

Comment: Perhaps `i1 <- union(which(duplicated(df1$Y)),  which(duplicated(df1$X))); df1[sample(setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df1)), i1), 3, replace=FALSE),]`

Comment: @akrun this will produce 'unique' values but they are not randomly chosen from the whole set. Not sure if that's quite what was asked but perhaps that's why you've not put it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start by sampling (randomizing) the rows of your original data, then subset only those rows where `X` or `Y` are *not* duplicated and then select the first, last or any `n` (=3) number of rows (you could use `sample` again), you should be fine, I think.

```
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
head(subset(df[sample(nrow(df)),], !duplicated(X) & !duplicated(Y)), 3)
#    X Y
#6   4 5
#7  16 6
#10 11 9
```

---

In response to the comment by @Richo64, saying that this approach will not randomly select the pairs:

It *does* sample the pairs randomly because the first (inner most) thing I do is

```
df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

which samples the rows of the data *randomly*. Now, once we have done that, it's a random process which, say 4, in column X will come first and therefore will remain in the data because the other 4 is removed since it is a duplicated entry in X.

The same applies to values in `Y`.

It's obvious then, that after the sampling and subsetting, you are free to choose any 3 rows of the remaining data and even if you always selected the first 3 rows, you would still get a random selection that will differ every time you run it (except when it coincidently samples the same rows again).

Comment: As with akrun's answer, this will produce 'unique' values but they are not randomly chosen from the whole set. Not sure if that's quite what was asked.

Comment: @Richo64, I don't quite agree with that statement. One of the differences between my answer and akrun's comment is that I _first_ sample the rows of the data (i.e. _before_ I remove duplicates). That makes it a random selection of pairs. It doesn't create new pairs that were not in the initial data, like 5,10 would be, but I don't believe that was asked for.

Comment: Hi. I have been trying your solution and seems to work well. At least it provides a solid basis to solve my problem. In case someone is wondering about the applicability of the algorithm, I require to pick up elements at random in a matrix from different rows and columns.  Very grateful to you all.